# Are there method that can extract interaction between person in text?

Tags: extract, spacy, named-entity-recognition, interaction, dependency-parsing

I want to **extract interaction between persons** in short text. For example, "Sally will buy a new phone. Ted will help her." contains interaction between persons. However, "Japanese Karate champion won the first prize." and "Sally missed her friends, Ted and Tom" does not contain interaction between persons.

Is there any tools or methods that can extract interactions?

I tried Spacy dependency parsing. But it didn't work well, I think.

Comment: please show us what you tried